# Find bluetooth devices around an iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am trying to find devices with bluetooth turned on using an iPhone.

Which bluetooth service UUID should I look for?

This is the code I tried and using the simulator I cannot find any device:

```
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:
        @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1101"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1102"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1105"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1106"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1115"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1116"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1117"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0001"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0003"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0008"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0100"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"000F"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1101"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1116"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1000"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1001"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1002"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0010"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0011"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0012"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0013"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0014"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0015"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0016"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0017"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0018"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0019"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"001B"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"001E"],
          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"001F"],

          ]
                                       options:nil];
```

Comment: you can't get facility of bluetooth, in simulator.

Comment: Is there a way to try the bluetooth API without paying the 100$?

Comment: :) as far as, i know, it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

The ExternalAccessory framework gives you an easy way to list available devices using EAAccessoryManager.

```
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

You can't do this in the simulator.

Comment: This only lists connected devices and not all possibly available devices, right?

Comment: Yes. It only lists the ones connected via the settings